# List down all combinations based on the number of inputs and methods

Tags: java, combinations

## Abstract Version of This Question

I want to generate all possible assignment of numbers between `0` and `n-1` into `v` variables. I know, that there are `v^n` such assignments, therefore I started with a loop that generates the numbers `0..(v^n)-1`. How can I convert the enumeration number from the loop into an actual assignment? Im especially interested in the case where `n=4` and `v=7`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(v, n); ++i) {
    variable0 = ...;
    variable1 = ...;
    variable2 = ...;
    ...
    variable6 = ...;
}
```

#### Expected assignments

```
i       variable
        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  
---------------------------
0       0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1       0  0  0  0  0  0  1
2       0  0  0  0  0  0  2
3       0  0  0  0  0  0  3
4       0  0  0  0  0  1  0
...
12000   2  3  2  3  2  0  0
...
16383   3  3  3  3  3  3  3
```

## Original question

My goal is to assign a method to each input and get all possible combinations of methods to all the input.

Below are the codes (with the help of [from this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50782283/9434654**))

```
    public static final int FUNCTION_NUMBER = 3;
        public static String functionA() {
            return "A";
        }
        public static String functionB() {
            return "B";
        }
        public static String functionC() {
            return "C";
        }
        public static String callFunction(int function_index) {
            switch (function_index) {
            case 0:
                return functionA();
            case 1:
                return functionB();
            case 2:
                return functionC();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect value for function_index");
            }
        }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {

         int name_function_index = i / FUNCTION_NUMBER;
        int phone_no_function_index = i % FUNCTION_NUMBER; }
```

From the codes above, there is 3 methods (function A, B, C) and 2 inputs (name, phone no). So the possibility of all the combination is 3^2 = 9.
Thus, the output is given below.

```
  loop name phoneno
      0    A    A
      1    A    B
      2    A    C
      3    B    A
      4    B    B
      5    B    C
      6    C    A
      7    C    B
      8    C    C
```

My question is what if I have 4 methods(function A, B, C, D) and 7 inputs (firstname, lastname, phoneno, officeno, add, street, country)? So the combinations will be  4^7 = 16384. What are the formulas for the inputs in order to get all possible combination as given below?

```
   loop    firstname lastname phoneno officeno add street country
    0       A          A       A        A       A    A     A
    1       A          A       A        A       A    A     B
    2       A          A       A        A       A    A     C
    3       A          A       A        A       A    A     D
    ...
    12000   C          A       D        B       B    A     D
    ...
    16383   D          D       D        D       D    D     D



 public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 16383; i++) {
        int name_function_index= i / FUNCTION_NUMBER;
        int phone_no_function_index= i % FUNCTION_NUMBER;
        int office_no_function_index= ??
        int add_no_function_index= ??
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Java ain’t JavaScript - you can’t run java as a snippet

Comment: @Bohemian Sorry, I copied and paste the code at the wrong box. I edited.

Comment: If you really talked about the number of combinations between `f` functions and `i` inputs, then the answer would be `f·i`, but it seems like you are actually interested in the number of strings of length `n` using only `c` chars, and that is `c^n` (as you already know). What is the problem? Are you askig how to write `c^n` in Java? It's `Math.pow(c, n)`.

Comment: @Socowi The problem is I am not sure what are the formulas for  office_no_function_index and add_no_function_index based on the FUNCTION_NUMBER.

Comment: How should we know the formulas for `add_no_function_index` and `office_no_function_index` when we don't even know what these variables are supposed to be? Both of these variables appear only once in your question, namely as `var = ??`.

Comment: @Socowi the `add_no_function_index` and `office_no_function_index` returns functions a, b, c, and d. For example, `name_function_index` and `phone_no_function_index`, returns AA, AB, AC. So for `name_function_index` , `phone_no_function_index` , `add_no_function_index` and `office_no_function_index`, I would like to return AAAAAAA, AAAAAAB, etc.

Comment: You lost me. A variable cannot *return* something. And an `int` can not store a list of Strings. Anyway, you should include vital informations into your question instead of giving these informations as comments.

Comment: @Socowi I included the vital information in my question. Hope it helps to clarify your doubts.

Comment: @Bohemian I edited the question already. Hope this question is more clearly and to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: @EmmaE That's better. In combination with the linked question I was able to understand what you want. I voted to re-open the question. Until the question is re-opened, I cannot answer. I would have abstracted the question from terms like *phone*, *office*, and so on to make it easily understandable. I'll edit your question, that should help to re-open it soon.

Comment: Since the question does not seem to be re-opened soon, here's the answer: The formula for x-th variable  is `varx = i / n^x % n` with `n` being your `FUNCTION_NUMBER`. In your case, that's `var0 = i / 1 % 7; var1 = i / 7 % 7; var2 = i / 49 % 7` and so on. However, you should really use arrays and loops instead of doing these things manually.

Comment: @Socowi I tried your answer. However, there was `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`. Given 2 variables and 4 functions. Below are my codes `for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, FUNCTION_NUMBER); i++) {  var0 = i / FUNCTION_NUMBER^0 % FUNCTION_NUMBER;
    var1 =  i / FUNCTION_NUMBER^1 % FUNCTION_NUMBER;` The output given was Loop0: 01, Loop1: 01 Loop2: 01, Loop3: 10, Loop4: 10 Loop5: 10 and then, it was the exception.
 Hope that the question re-opened soon. So that we can see the codes more clearly.

Comment: @EmmaE `n^x` was just a mathematical formula and `var0`, `var1`, ... were just placeholders. In Java `^` is *not* the power function. In your case, you would have to write something like `i % FUNCTION_NUMBER` for `i / n^0 % n` and `i / (FUNCTION_NUMBER * FUNCTION_NUMBER) % FUNCTION_NUMBER` for `i / n^2 % n`.

Comment: @Socowi Now, I understand what does `^`. I followed your formula for var0 and var1. However the output was Loop0: 00, Loop1: 10, Loop2: 30, Loop3: 00, Loop4: 10 Loop5: 30 Loop6: 00, Loop7: 10. The loop keep repeating after Loop2.

Comment: @EmmaE Could it be that you just copied that `i / (FUNCTION_NUMBER * FUNCTION_NUMBER) % FUNCTION_NUMBER` from my last comment, even though thats the formula for the 3rd variable, not the 2nd (var0 ist the 1st). Please read my full answer carefully. I think you should be able to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Changing Base Makes Conversion Obvious

When you have *v* variables *var<sub>0</sub>* to *var<sub>v-1</sub>* and want to assign numbers between *0* and *n-1* to them, you can convert the enumeration number *i* to base *n* and select one digit for each variable.

#### Example

You have *v=3* variables and n=2 numbers. You know that there are *v<sup>n</sup>* possible assignments and enumerate them with the counter *i*. Normally, humans count in decimal (base 10), but this time, we count in binary (base 2).

```
    i     |   Assignment
dec   bin | var2 var1 var0 
----------+----------------
  0   000 |  0    0    0
  1   001 |  0    0    0  
  2   010 |  0    1    0
  3   011 |  0    1    1
  4   100 |  1    0    0
  5   101 |  1    0    1
  6   110 |  1    1    0
  7   111 |  1    1    1
```

The three digits of *i*'s binary representation directly correspond to the variable assignment enumerated with *i*.

## Converting Enumeration Number *i* Into an Assignment

To get an assignment, we have extract the *v* digits of *i* in base *n*.

Assume you had the base 10 (normal/decimal) number *i=3149* and wanted to extract its four digits. You would do

```
digit0 = i % 10;        // same as i / 1 % 10
digit1 = i / 10 % 10;
digit2 = i / 100 % 10;
digit3 = i / 1000 % 10;
```

The formula for the *x*-th digit is *i / 10 <sup>x</sup> % 10*.
Now if the base *n* was something different than 10, then the formula would be *i / n <sup>x</sup> % n*.

#### Example

A small example program for *v=3* and *n=4*:

```
int var0, var1, var2;
int n = 4;
System.out.println("   i | Assignment");
System.out.println("-----+-----------");
for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(n, 3); ++i) {
    var0 = i % n;           // = i / Math.pow(n, 0) % n 
    var1 = i / n % n;       // = i / Math.pow(n, 1) % n 
    var2 = i / (n * n) % n; // = i / Math.pow(n, 2) % n
    System.out.format("%4d | %2d %2d %2d\n", i, var2, var1, var0);
}
```

prints

```
   i | Assignment
-----+-----------
   0 |  0  0  0
   1 |  0  0  1
   2 |  0  0  2
   3 |  0  0  3
   4 |  0  1  0
     .
     .
     .
  61 |  3  3  1
  62 |  3  3  2
  63 |  3  3  3
```

## Improvements

For a shorter, cleaner, and more extendable program, you shouldn't write things like

```
var5 = i / (n * n * n * n * n) % n
```

manually. Use arrays and loops.